# I need to split two dates into separate values

Tags: javascript, apify

I need some JavaScript to separate two dates shown like this `08 Oct - 12 Oct 2019` into separate values `10/08/2019` & `10/12/2019` when I scrape a website using Apify.

I've started using Apify to scrape some event data from a local theatre website so I can supply the same information on my own. The theatre company writes the start and end date within one paragraph tag which means it returns both dates in one cell.

In order for my website to use the theatre companies date data, I need each date to be formatted like this `mm/dd/yyyy` and I need each date to be separated into their own values. Is there a way with javascript to separate the dates in the example provided and format them into American date form?

As an example, this is one of the pages I'm scraping data from https://theatreroyal.com/whats-on/the-rocky-horror-show/

```
async function pageFunction(context) {
    const { request, log, jQuery } = context;

    const $ = jQuery;
    const title = $('title').text();

    log.info(`URL: ${request.url} TITLE: ${title}`);

    return {
        url: request.url,
        name: $('.c-pg-masthead-wrapper--events-fixed .c-pg-title').text(),
        date: $('.c-pg-masthead-wrapper--events-fixed .c-pg-subtitle').text().trim()
    };
}
```

Currently, the above script returns the date as it is written, ie `10 October - 12 Oct 2019` which is unusable for what I need.

I would really appreciate some help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I added a version that can handle dates across years too:  `10 Dec 2019 - 12 Jan 2020`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that will return from and to

I used

- https://regex101.com/r/5fjHtF/1 to create the RegEx
- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to create the vars from the match in one go
- The [date constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) using
- [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and
- [toLocaleDateString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) to format the date

```js
const format = { month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit', year: 'numeric' };

const getDates = (dateStr) => {
  [_, fd, fm, td, tm, year] = dateStr.match(/(\d{2}) ([a-zA-Z]{3}) - (\d{2}) ([a-zA-Z]{3}) (\d{4})/);
  const from = new Date(`${fd} ${fm} ${year} 15:00:00`); // using 15:00 for dst reasons
  const to   = new Date(`${td} ${tm} ${year} 15:00:00`);
  return {
    "from": from.toLocaleDateString("en-US", format),
      "to":   to.toLocaleDateString("en-US", format)
  }
};

const date = '08 Oct - 12 Oct 2019'; // change to your date string
const dates = getDates(date); // how to call it
console.log(dates.from, dates.to); // how to use the dates returned
```

Here is a version that can handle strings that cross years

```js
const format = { month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit', year: 'numeric' };

const getDates = (dateStr) => {
  const sameYear = dateStr.split(" ").length === 6; // dd mmm - dd mmm yyyy
  let fy="";
  if (sameYear) {
    [_, fd, fm, td, tm, year] = dateStr.match(/(\d{2}) ([a-zA-Z]{3}) - (\d{2}) ([a-zA-Z]{3}) (\d{4})/);
  }
  else {
    [_, fd, fm, fy, td, tm, year] = dateStr.match(/(\d{2}) ([a-zA-Z]{3}) (\d{4}) - (\d{2}) ([a-zA-Z]{3}) (\d{4})/);
  }
  const from = new Date(`${fd} ${fm} ${fy?fy:year} 15:00:00`); // using 15:00 for dst reasons
  const to   = new Date(`${td} ${tm} ${year} 15:00:00`);
  return {
    "from": from.toLocaleDateString("en-US", format),
      "to":   to.toLocaleDateString("en-US", format)
  }
};

const date1 = '08 Oct - 12 Oct 2019'; // change to your date string
const dates1 = getDates(date1); // how to call it
console.log(dates1.from, dates1.to); // how to use the dates returned

const date2 = '08 Dec 2019 - 12 Jan 2020'; // change to your date string
const dates2 = getDates(date2); // how to call it
console.log(dates2.from, dates2.to); // how to use the dates returned
```

Comment: I'm not particularly familiar with javascript so how do I implement this code into my Apify script?

Comment: If apify supports ES6, then just add the script, substituting my `const date = '08 Oct - 12 Oct 2019';` with your date and change console.log to whatever you want with the date

Comment: Yes, Apify supports ES6 so this should work fine. I would put it into the function and return an object with `start` and `end`.